# Clone HDD to SDD?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, sata, clone

To speed up my PC, I want to replace my 2TB hard drive with a 2TB SATA SSD. I've replaced my hard drives before, cloning the old one to the new one with a [hard drive docking station](https://www.sitecom.com/lu/usb-30-hard-drive-docking-station-sata-25-35/md-394/p/1745).

Now, I'm wondering if I can expect to be able to clone an HDD to an SDD and substitute it in my PC just as I could with an HDD (given it's the same SATA interface, although a different physical size).

Comment: If using Windows, please see [this](https://superuser.com/a/1581804/529800) answer

Comment: You can also consider this one: https://superuser.com/a/1091547/910769 or the answers here: https://superuser.com/q/1147171/910769

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a fairly normal way to commence using an SSD as a system drive. Many SSDs come with a free utility that you can download (for example Samsung supply "Data Migration Software", and Seagate have "Disk Wizard") or you can, as I have done, back up your system HDD to an image with something like Macrium Reflect, and just restore the image to the SSD. Macrium Reflect in fact has a direct disk clone option, and if the SSD is larger than the source HDD can expand the partition to fill the drive.

Some SSD manufacturers supply little trays that hold a 2.5 inch SSD and have mounting holes to fit a 3.5" drive bay, and maybe even some screws, or you can buy these things separately.

The SSD can be mounted in the PC or laptop and connected via SATA or in a docking station or USB enclosure.

Comment: OK, cool. I guess directly cloning with my docking station will work then.

Comment: @mrgou see edits above.